# How to render no-table HTML form into two columns with CSS using classes?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I am trying to format a two-column form so that:

- the labels are above each input field or text area
- everything in class *col1* is in the column on the left
- everything in class *col2* is in the column on the right
- everything in class *col12* spans both columns

Here is the HTML code I need this to work with:

```
    <div id="contactForm">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <h3>Contact us</h3>
        <p>To send us a work order, fill in the form below.<br /><strong>All the (*) fields are mandatory.</strong></p>
        <fieldset>
          <div class="col1">
            <label for="form_firstname">Firstname <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="form_firstname" name="form_firstname" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <label for="form_lastname">Lastname <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="form_lastname" name="form_lastname" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col1">
            <label for="form_address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="form_address" name="form_address" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <label for="form_city">City</label>
            <input type="text" id="form_city" name="form_city" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col1">
            <label for="form_email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="form_email" name="form_email" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <label for="form_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="form_phone" name="form_phone" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col12">
            <label for="form_attachment">Add Attachment <span class="form_attachment">*</span></label>
            <textarea id="form_attachment" name="form_attachment" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col12">
            <label for="form_message">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col12">
            <label for="form_message">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

How do I code the CSS to style this HTML as required?

Here is the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx2gjpdw/1/).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, use a front-end framework such as Bootstrap, Foundation until you get mature enough

Comment: Well, I'd rather do it from scratch than have to overdo it.

Comment: I guess you're right, sometimes it's better than bloating your project with useless styles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
#contactForm{
    width: 80%;
}
label,.col1,.col2,.col12{display: block;}
.col1{ float:right;}
.col2{float:left;}
.col12{clear:both;}
textarea{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rx2gjpdw/3/